# ProgressDialogController mahapps, problems closing popup

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, modal-dialog, mahapps.metro

I am creating a WPF project using Mahapps Metro .

My problem is that I would launch from DetailPage.xaml frame , which is embedded in MainWindow.xaml , the wait modal mahapps provides.
So I did two methods that open and close , but at the end he says that is no longer the dialog .
Does anyone have solutions ?

my code in frame `DetailPage.xaml`

```
private void Meeting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow w = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;
    w.showMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow();


    var MIDClick = sender as Button;
    String MID = MIDClick.Tag as String;

    ...mycode...                

    w.closeMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow();
}
```

my code in `MainWindow.xaml` (MetroWindow)

```
public ProgressDialogController dialog;

public async void showMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow()
{
    dialog = await this.ShowProgressAsync(Properties.strings.attendi, Properties.strings.aggiornamentoMeetingsInCorso, false) as ProgressDialogController;
}

public async void closeMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow()
{
    await dialog.CloseAsync();
}
```

my error:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are doing a "Fire and Forget" (`async void`). In other words you are calling `showMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow` and rigth after you are calling `closeMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow` before `dialog` is initiated.

Solution :

```
private async void Meeting_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainWindow w = (MainWindow)App.Current.MainWindow;
    await w.showMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow();


    var MIDClick = sender as Button;
    String MID = MIDClick.Tag as String;

    ...mycode...                

    await w.closeMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow();
}
```

the code in your `MainWindow.xaml`

```
public ProgressDialogController dialog;

public async Task showMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow()
{
    dialog = await this.ShowProgressAsync(Properties.strings.attendi, Properties.strings.aggiornamentoMeetingsInCorso, false) as ProgressDialogController;
}

public async Task closeMessaggeAsyncFromMainWindow()
{
    await dialog.CloseAsync();
}
```

With this solution you are not doing a "Fire and Forget". You are waiting for the dialog to open and close with the `await`.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to close it using the dialog cancel Button

```
        var settings = new MetroDialogSettings()
        {

            NegativeButtonText = "cancel",
            DialogMessageFontSize = 25,
            DialogTitleFontSize = 25,
            DialogResultOnCancel = MessageDialogResult.Canceled,

        };
        ProgressDialogController controller =
                await this.ShowProgressAsync("Title", "Message", true, settings);
        controller.SetCancelable(true);

        controller.Canceled += controller_Canceled;

        //after your job

        if(controller.IsOpen)
             await controller.CloseAsync();
```

and this is the cancel event

```
    private async void controller_Canceled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressDialogController controller_ = (ProgressDialogController)sender;
        await controller_.CloseAsync();
    }
```